# C# list of array type

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

I want to create a list of array type.
I want to create array containing values :

```
array = [a,b];
```

Then i want to put this array in list :

```
List<Array> list = new List<Array>( );
```

I am able to do this with list of string type but no luck with array type :

```
List<String> list = new List<String>( );
```

I am from javascript background, not much familiar with concept of collections in c#. 
Also how can i create array in c# like we do in javascript :

```
var arrTemp = ["a", "b"];
```

Comment: What are you putting in the array? You need for example `List<string[]> list;`

Comment: @Lee working on code which has list<array> as return type. Can't change that.

Comment: Your js statement in c# will look like new List<String>{"a", "b"} or new [] {"a", "b"}, but those answers are downvoted :)

Comment: Is the type you want to store in an array is dynamic/changing? or it just one type?

Comment: @jtabuloc one type.

Comment: thanks  @MaksimSimkin this comments solve my another problem. :)

Comment: Specific array types are subclasses of `Array` so if your question is how to create an instance of type `Array` you can do `Array a = new string[] { "a", "b" };`.

Comment: @Lee - but after that, getting the  `"b"` from your `a` isn't so easy.

Comment: @Lee `Array a = new string[] { "a", "b" };` worked for me. thank you...

Comment: @Deepakgupta It was answer with the most downvotes :)

Comment: yes @MaksimSimkin... i learned few things about c# collection from this down voted question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since your array is `string[]`:

```
 var arrTemp = ["a", "b"];
```

you have to declare the required `list` as `List<string[]>`:

```
 // list of string arrays
 List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>() {
   new string[] {"a", "b"} 
 };
```

In case you want to be able to put *any* array into the `list` declare it as loose as possible (`List<object[]>`):

```
 // list of abitrary arrays
 List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>() {
   new string[] {"a", "b"},
   new double[] {123.45, 789.12, 333.55}, 
   new object[] {'a', "bcd", 1, 244.95, true},
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

`var test = new List<int[]>();`

Answer (score 0):

You *can* actually create a list of arrays:

```
var listOfArrays = new List<Array>();
```

The problem with this is that it's difficult to use the arrays themselves, as the `Array` type doesn't support array syntax. (e.g. You can't do `listOfArrays[0][0]`) Instead, you have to use the `GetValue` method to do your retrieval:

```
var obj = listOfArrays[0].GetValue(0);
```

But this has another problem. The `GetValue` method returns `object`, so while you could always cast it to the desired type, you lose your type safety in choosing this approach.

Alternatively, you could just store `object[]` arrays:

```
var listOfArrays = new List<object[]>();
var obj = listOfArrays[0][0];
```

But while this solves the issue of the array notation, you still lose the type safety.

Instead, if at all possible, I would recommend finding a particular type, then just have arrays of that type:

```
var listOfArrays = new List<string[]>();
string s = listOfArrays[0][0];
```

Answer (score -1):

for example, an array of strings would be

```
var arrayOfString = new string[]{"a","b"};
// or shorter form: string[] arrayOfString  = {"a","b"};
// also: var arrayOfString = new[] { "a", "b" }
```

And then creating a list-of-arrayOfString would be

```
var listOfArrayOfString = new List<string[]>();
```

This works with any type, for example if you had a class `MyClass`

```
var arrayOfMyClass = new MyClass[]{ ... }; // ... is you creating instances of MyClass
var list = new List<MyClass[]>();
```